# Почему не получается задать 3 атрибута в $.attr

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, attr

Вот так работает

```
$("#img").attr(
        "width",200,
        "height",300
);
$("#img").attr(
        "src",images[currentImg]
);
```

Вот так НЕ РАБОТАЕТ

```
    $("#img").attr(
            "width",200,
            "height",300,
            "src",images[currentImg]
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Вот так работает" - боюсь, Вы чего-то не замечаете.

```
$("#img").attr({
  width: 200,
  height: 300,
  src: images[currentImg]
});
```

Comment: оказывается я не правильно писал используя "height",300, .... надо было "height":300,  с двоеточием

Comment: @Stein_ и фигурные скобки, как объект.